# cabal install suppresses output

Tags: haskell, io, hook, cabal

I have created a cabal package which uses custom build-type. In Setup.hs I trigger a `postCopy` hook with which I intend to do some IO. In the body of the trigger I use `putStrLn` to output a line.

When I `cabal install` the package, the output gets logged into a text file instead of showing at the console. A bit more insight: I think the problem relates to all triggers, not only `postCopy`, and `cabal install`. Because if for example I have a `postConf` trigger (performing some IO) and run `cabal configure`, the IO will work as expected. But when I do `cabal install` I'll have the same problem for the `postConf` trigger as well.

Is there a way to show the output from the trigger in stdout?

```
>cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Perhaps there is another approach which addresses your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, during installs `cabal` runs Setup.hs with both stdout and stderr redirected to a file. There are two reasons for this:

1. To save the install output in the ~/.cabal/logs/... directory
2. So it can run parallel installs and the output of concurrent jobs won't get mixed up with each other

You can use the `--build-log` option to tell cabal where to write logging information to, e.g.:

```
cabal install --build-log /tmp/foo
```

Also, if you are running a Unix/Linux like system, you can write to a device like `/dev/tty` and get output back to the user's terminal (if there is one.) For example:

```
import Distribution.Simple
import System.IO

main = do
  putStrLn "=== I am here in Setup.hs"
  withFile "/dev/tty" AppendMode $ \h -> do
    hPutStrLn h "--- writing to /dev/tty"
  defaultMain
```

Of course, this is OS-specific code, and it might cause problems for other users if they aren't using the same OS as you are.

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly ask for a single-threaded build, cabal will send its output to stdout. Use

```
cabal install -j1
```

to make this request.